# How do you add CMYK values together?

Tags: math, colors, cmyk

I'm trying to figure out the math in a python program im creating that can simulate mixing paint in real life, but I cannot find any info about any CMYK equations on the internet.

Here's an example of what I need to do...

If the CMYK value of Paint Bucket A is (C=10, M=20, Y= 60, k=10)

and the CMYK value of Paint Bucket B is (C=30, m=60, y=100, k=15)

and these two paint buckets were mixed together, what would the CMYK value be of the resulting bucket, and how could I figure that out mathematically?

Also, say Bucket A has twice as much paint as Bucket B, how would that change the equation? And also, what if say three different buckets were mixed together?

First I thought averaging each value together would work. For example if I mixed
(0,100,0,0)
with
(100,0,0,0)
and that would give me
(50,50,0,0)
But then I thought "basically that's mixing pure cyan with pure magenta and it should create"
(100,100,0,0)

So I guess the reason it's complicated for me is because the percentages of each color don't have to add up to 100.
Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMYK + CMYK = ? CMYK / 2 =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527451/cmyk-cmyk-cmyk-2)

Comment: I don't think those equation work, because let's say you add paint A = 100,100,0,0) with paint B = (0,100,100,0). If my math is right, their equation would give me (100,100,100,0). But in reality if you mix paint A =(1 Cyan, 1 Magenta) and paint B = (1 Magenta, 1 Yellow), shouldn't it equal a paint that's (1 Cyan, 2 Magenta, 1 Yellow), not (1 Cyan, 1 Magenta, 1 Yellow)?